# How to update iPhone 6s with IOS 9?

Tags: iphone, software-update

I have an iPhone 6s, which has been reset to firmware defaults. I started it, did the initialization to get WLAN and tried to update the OS. Whenever I try it, I get the error, that the search for updates failed.

Next I captured the traffic of the iPhone on my WLAN router. The iPhone tries to access `17.253.79.204` and does the following two requests:

```
GET /assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdate.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: mesu.apple.com
Accept: */*
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 24 Mar 2020 17:01:51 GMT
User-Agent: MobileAsset/1.1
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Sat, 04 Apr 2020 11:36:19 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=300, public
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: keep-alive
Via: http/1.1 dedus1-edge-bx-014.ts.apple.com (ApacheTrafficServer/8.0.6)
Server: ATS/8.0.6
CDNUUID: 9baa646f-1e5f-4062-b6a4-a4679d31306a-1017952490
X-Cache: hit-fresh

GET /assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdateDocumentation/com_apple_MobileAsset_SoftwareUpdateDocumentation.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: mesu.apple.com
Accept: */*
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 24 Mar 2020 16:38:12 GMT
User-Agent: MobileAsset/1.1
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Sat, 04 Apr 2020 11:36:19 GMT
Etag: "a37f559a333d191f18284618a1b179fc"
Cache-Control: max-age=300, public
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: keep-alive
Via: http/1.1 dedus1-edge-bx-014.ts.apple.com (ApacheTrafficServer/8.0.6)
Server: ATS/8.0.6
CDNUUID: 9baa646f-1e5f-4062-b6a4-a4679d31306a-1017952695
X-Cache: hit-fresh
```

It seems to me that the `mesu.apple.com` server does not give my iPhone any updates.

The question is: why?

The iPhone has been reset to firmware defaults. Why are the firmware defaults not sufficient to get updates? Is it possible to brick an iPHone by resetting it?

Comment: couldn't it be a space issue?

Comment: By "firmware defaults" do you mean you did an "erase all content and settings?" That will delete everything on the phone and give you plenty of space. I would be tempted to plug it into a Mac or PC, launch iTunes and see if iTunes will sense the version of iOS on it and offer to upgrade it. I have seen either the iPhone upgrade or the iTunes upgrade fail while the other works. Don't know why, tho...

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes everything has been erased. After that I set language and wlan and the settings I was not able to cancel.

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you. That is **very** odd. you may want to put the phone in Recovery Mode, attache it to the computer and see if iTunes will update it then. After that I am out of ideas...